# Can't download Debian's Two Blu-Ray Disk

Tags: debian

I use this command:

```
$ jigdo-lite --noask debian-7.1.0-amd64-BD-1.jigdo
$ jigdo-lite --noask debian-7.1.0-amd64-BD-2.jigdo
```

I'm already download 41Gb. But It is stuck with next err:

```
--2013-10-15 15:27:36--  ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/virtuoso-opensource/virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin_6.1.4+dfsg1-7_amd64.deb
  (try: 5) => ‘debian-7.1.0-amd64-BD-1.iso.tmpdir/ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/virtuoso-opensource/virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin_6.1.4+dfsg1-7_amd64.deb’
Connecting to ftp.debian.org (ftp.debian.org)|130.89.148.12|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... 
Error in server response, closing control connection.
Retrying.
```

Is there any hooks or alternatives to Jigdo?

I'm really do not understand why there is no .torrent files. I can't see the progress of downloading, I have no idea which of deb packages doesn't downloaded yet, except this virtuoso. Is there another way to get Debian's Two Blu-Ray Disk?

Comment: I guess there are just too few users wanting a Debian blu-ray (maybe you are the first one? :)). For a torrent there must be a complete image somewhere, whereas jigdo just builds the image from individual downloaded packages instead of downloading one large single file.

However I cannot spot the cause of your problem. The file jigdo tries to download definitely exists. But you could try to use a different mirror.